# How to prefix a Lua table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a lua file whose content is lua Table as below:
`A={}`,
`A.B={}`,
`A.B.C=0;`,

The problem is I want to add prefix XYZ before each above statements. So after the parse the database should have something loke this:
`XYZ.A={}`,
`XYZ.A.B={}`,
`XYZ.A.B.C={}`,

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can load the file with `XYZ` as is environment: `loadfile("mydata","t",XYZ)`. See [loadfile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-loadfile) in the manual.

This works in Lua 5.2. For Lua 5.1, use `loadfile` followed by `setfenv`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford polluting your global space with `A`, simply assign it later:

```
-- load the file
-- if XYZ doesn't exist, XYZ = { A = A } would be probably shorter
XYZ.A = A
A = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
XYZ = {}
XYZ.A = {}
XYZ.A.B = {}
XYZ.A.B.C = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you simply do:

```
XYZ = {
    A = {
        B = {
            C = 0
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to nest objects so deep then you may do:

```
XYZ = {
    A = A
}

A = nil
```

This assumes that you have already declared the object `A` before.