# Lua dont allow table append

Tags: lua, lua-table

I already have a lua-table `A={}, A.B={}` under global variable. I have a function on the call of what creates lua table `D1={}, D1.D2={}`, but the porblem is this function places the table in global variable list. When i print all lua values, it prints:
`A={}, A.B={}, D1=={}, D1.D2={}`. Is there a way I can create the function under table under `A={}, A.B={}` which mean i want output as:
`A={}, A.B={}, A.B.D1=={}, A.B.D1.D2={}`. I dont want to use table.insert() since the hirarchy of source-table is not known.

Comment: Note that `table.insert` only works with index insertion. You can't insert by key with it.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525622/how-to-prefix-a-lua-table ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do here, is pass the table to the function that creates `D1` and `D1.D2` so you can append those values wherever you want them.

```
function addTable(tbl)
    tbl.D1 = {}
    tbl.D1.D2 = {'test'}
end

addTable(A.B)
-- now you can call A.B.D1.D2
print(A.B.D1.D2[1]) -- prints 'test'
```

Comment: You don't need to do the assignment in pieces either. You can just use `tbl.D1 = { D2 = {'test'} }` in the body of addTable.